# puppet agent inside docker stuck in restart loop

Tags: docker, puppet

I'm trying to play around with configuring agents and such through Docker. I have this compose file:

```
services:
    puppetserver:
        container_name: puppetserver
        hostname: puppet
        image: puppet/puppetserver
        links: 
            - puppetdb
        networks:
            - puppetnet
        depends_on:
            - puppetdb
    puppetdb:
        container_name: puppetdb
        hostname: puppetdb
        image: puppet/puppetdb
        networks:
            - puppetnet
        restart: always
    agent:
        container_name: agent
        hostname: agent
        image: puppet/puppet-agent
        links:
            - puppetserver
        networks:
            - puppetnet
        restart: always

networks:
    puppetnet:
        name: puppetnet
```

After I spin it up, the agent restarts a few times waiting for the puppet server to come up but then goes into restart and stays there forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the [puppet/puppet-agent](https://hub.docker.com/r/puppet/puppet-agent-ubuntu) page closer and it says

> Note that this is of limited use outside testing, in that this code changes the running container, which then exits.

So the infinite restarts is to be expected.